# Could not autowired field using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am new to spring, 
I have implemented factory pattern using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean like below..

```
public interface Printer{
 public void print();
}

public class Printer1 implements Printer{
 @Override
 public void print(){
  System.out.println("printer1");
 }
}

public class Printer2 implements Printer{
 @Override
 public void print(){
  System.out.println("printer2");
 }
}
```

and factory interface

```
public interface PrinterFactory{
 public printer getPrinter(String printerName);
}
```

am using annotation based

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackage)
public class PrinterConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean createFactoryBean() {
  ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factory = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
  factory.setServiceLocatorInterface(PrinterFactory.class);
  return factory;
 }

 @Bean(name = "printer1")
 @Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
 public Printer1 printer1Service(){
  return new Printer1();
 }

 @Bean(name = "printer2")
 @Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
 public Printer2 printer1Service(){
  return new Printer2();
 }
}
```

and calling like below:

```
    @Autowired
    PrinterFactory printerFactory;

    printerFactory.getPrinter("printer1");
```

getting below exceptions :

```
Could not autowire field: org.test.myproject.PrinterFactory  org.test.myproject.controller.MyController.printerFactory ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.test.myproject.PrinterFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
```

can anyone tell me where i am going wrong??

Comment: "No qualifying bean of type"...? Seems that you removed the most important part of the stack trace. Also, you have the same `printer1Service` method twice which makes it evident that this is not the code you're actually running.

Comment: There is no `@Autowired` anywhere in your question, yet the issue is with `@Autowired`. Also please fix formatting as it is hard to understand your question.

Comment: @kryger, due to security concern, i have not pasted acutal one...now i have updated exception properly